# looking for line and linenumber in text file

Tags: python

I'm making a extra function for my chat program which allows you to register by typing a specific command that makes the host script save your peername and a name you insert in the terminal, its saved like this 57883:Jack in a txt file (names.txt) on the host machine. if a number of people have registered it'll look like this

```
57883:jack 
57884:bob
57885:connor
57886:james
57887:zzhshsb93838
57887:ryan
```

when someone sends a message i want to know if his/her name is registered and if so, get the name to send to the client, so instead of seeing the peername the client will see the name of the person sending the message.
in order to do that i need to know if the peername is in the file and if so; where in the file, in which line. i've got this so far:

```
 peer = sock.getpeername()
 with open('names.txt', 'r') as d:
     lines = d.readlines()
     for peer in lines:
```

and i don't know how to find out in which line it was found, and when i know that how to seperate 57883 and ack and select jack and save it. Cheers!

Comment: why do you want the line number?

Comment: @AnandSKumar i need the line number in order to retrieve the name

Comment: How large are you expecting this file to get? I ask, because I feel like this is headed towards XY-problem. If what you want to do is map number to name, there are better choices, from a dictionary to SQL. Your way will work, yes, but it's liable to be super slow.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen not big at all, probably just like above.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        numb, name = line.rstrip().split(":")
        print i, numb, name
```

You can ask Python to provide a tuple of *line number* and *line content* for each line of the file (see `enumerate(f)`). Then you remove the line terminator (see `line.rstrip()`) and split the line to parts separated by the provided character (see `split(":")`). You have all three components available then.

Comment: Please add comments to your answer/code, posting the code here is not a good style.

Comment: @Alexezio Fixed. Sorry.

Comment: @dlask how do i select 'jack' after that?